# Test the convergence of complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to test the convergence of the complex series $a_n = n(3+i)^n$.

I used the ratio test and I got $1/(3+i)$. I am unable to decide it is greater or less than 1, as we do not have ordered property in $\mathbb{C}$.

Please help.

Comment: The ratio test is based on the computation of the limit of $|a_{n+1}| / |a_n|$, so it must be an (extended) real number.

Comment: The ratio test is about ratios of norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recall that $|a+ib| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $

$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|(n+1)(3+i)^{n+1}|}{|(n)(3+i)^{n}|} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|n+1|}{|n|}|3+i|
\end{align} =\sqrt{9 + 1} = \sqrt{10} > 1$

Comment: Thank you. Such as easy explaination.